# Custom emacs-like key bindings on os x: DefaultKeyBinding.dict not working as expected

Tags: macos, emacs, key-bindings

I'm trying to add to the emacs-like key bindings in OS X 10.7.5.  In particular, in the default key bindings, alt-d and alt-b insert special characters, while I would like them to delete a word and move back a word. I've created a file `~\Library\KeyBindings\DefaultKeyBinding.dict` with the following content:

```
{
    "~d" = "deleteWordForward:";
}
```

(as suggested in the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20146972/is-there-a-way-to-make-alt-f-and-alt-b-jump-word-forward-and-backward-instead-of?rq=1))
and opened a new terminal window (I tried rebooting, too) but now the alt-d combination just beeps at me, and does nothing else.  Any clues?

Comment: Can you please help me understand why the standard Emacs key-bindings don't work for you?  For example, putting these inside the `.emacs` file in the home directory seem to work well:  `(global-set-key (kbd "M-b") 'backward-kill-word)` `(global-set-key (kbd "M-d") 'kill-word)`.  I have never had to play around with `~\Library\KeyBindings\DefaultKeyBinding.dict` and I've been using Emacs on OSX for about a year now.

Comment: I want to use the emacs keybindings *outside* of the GUI version of emacs, e.g. in a terminal window.  But specifically, the usual emacs keybindings do not work in the *console / terminal* emacsclient/server version of emacs.  I use this version frequently because it starts instantly and that feature is useful for quick editing tasks, and for editing 'git' commit messages and rebase scripts.

Comment: Note that DefaultKeyBinding.dict is good for mappings in standard OS X text fields (e.g. in TextEdit, in web page text boxes, in address bars, etc.), not in Terminal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do the trick -- within the Terminal.app *Keyboard* settings, check the box `Use option as meta key`.  [I verified the solution works with OSX Snow Leopard 10.6.8.]  Solution obtained from here:  http://iancwill.com/blog/?p=116

[image: Example]

Comment: BINGO!   I owe you a beer.